# Grouping neighbors in a 2D list in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, connected-components

I have a 2D list which is a game board containing either an empty space which is a dot (.), an "x" or an "o". I also have a list called groups = [] Each element in this list will be a another list (group), and that list will contain n amount of lists, where each list will look like this: [x, y] (x and y coordinates).

A group is made only of o's or x'es. A group might only be one stone (x or o). A stone belongs to a group if it has one or more connections. A connection is where the stone (x for example) has a same "color" (x - black, o - white) stone next to it (x - 1, x + 1) or above/below it (y - 1, y + 1). Here's a 4x4 board example.

```
[['x', 'x', '.', 'x'],
 ['x', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['x', 'x', '.', '.']]
```

here it would look like this:

```
groups = [ [ [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1] ], [ [0, 3], [1, 3] ], [ [3, 0] ] ]
```

I've came up with a code, which works but isn't efficient enough. Also, if my explanation of the problem isn't good enough, write a comment and I'll try to explain it further. Here's the code I've came up with:

```
    if len(cells) > 0:
        while len(niezuzyte) != 0:   
            grupa = [niezuzyte[0]]
            zuzyte.append(niezuzyte[0])
            niezuzyte = [x for x in cells if x not in zuzyte]
            for ziomek in grupa:
                for cel in cells:
                    if abs(cel[0] - ziomek[0]) <= 1 and abs(cel[1] - ziomek[1]) <= 1:
                        if abs(cel[0] - ziomek[0]) + abs(cel[1] - ziomek[1]) < 2 and cel not in grupa:
                                zuzyte.append(cel)
                                grupa.append(cel)
                do_wyjeby.append(grupa)
                niezuzyte = [x for x in cells if x not in zuzyte]
```

the list names are polish but I hope it doesn't matter too much, cells is a group with indexes of all either x'es or o's on the board. The code also gives me groups of [y, x] instead of [x, y] but that shouldn't matter too much. Any tips/help would be greatly appreaciated, thanks!

Comment: sorry if a similar problem was already posted, but i was looking and couldn't find my answer, thanks!

Comment: how would it look like if there are also `o` in your data? Because in your list of coordinates is no hint on whether it is a group of `x` or `o`

Comment: Are you open to using numpy and that ecosystem?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for labelling of connected components, which is provided by, among others, [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/). Start by turning your list into an array:

```
import numpy as np
board = np.array([
    ['x', 'x', '.', 'x'],
    ['x', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['x', 'x', '.', '.']
])
```

You can get the connected components for a given "color" by masking that color and getting the [labels](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) for it:

```
from skimage.measure import label
labels, count = label(board == 'x', return_num=True, connectivity=1)
```

You can extract the coordinates into the format you want using [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
groups = [np.argwhere(labels == x) for x in range(1, count + 1)]
```

To get coordinates of `o`s, do the same thing, but for `board == 'o'`. Keep in mind that the data format here is not particularly useful for indexing, so unless you have some specific analysis in mind, you might consider other formats.

If you want the `x` and `o` data intermingled, `skimage.measure.label` will correctly label any different regions in an integer image. For example:

```
board = np.array([
    ['x', 'x', '.', 'x'],
    ['x', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
    ['x', 'x', '.', '.']
])
iboard = np.zeros_like(board, dtype='uint8')
iboard[board == 'x'] = 1
iboard[board == 'o'] = 2
labels, count = label(iboard, return_num=True, connectivity=1)
```

Now `labels` will look like this:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 0, 0]])
```

You can then apply the comprehension with `np.argwhere` to all the labels at once.

Comment: Nice! I had the exact same approach waiting to post, but what to do when there are also `o` in the field. for label_image I took `board!='.'` so `x` and `o` are identified as clusters but at the end we just have increasing ints, so they are mixed.

Comment: @Rabinzel. I would just process them separately. Without further information, it's hard to tell which one OP actually wants.

Comment: Oh you edited your post again. True, propably doing it twice is the easiest way.

Comment: @Rabinzel. I've made one more edit

Comment: yep, that was what I meant. Both `o` and `x` are identified as cluster but you can't tell if e.g. cluster 1 represents `x` or `o`. If it doesn't matter -> perfect, else as you said, just running it twice will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MadPhysicist for the in depth solution, is it possible without scikit? I am doing a CodeWars project and scikit is not allowed. Here's some more info: Bascically I am making a game of Go and after every move, i need to check for opponent's stone liberties (no need to explain that), so when a white (o) makes a move (places an o stone on a board) i need to check ONLY for x'es, opposite happens for black, also thanks for the numpy recomendation, I am still a begineer and never really looked into that so I'll do just that, anyway, thanks again!

Comment: You can implement [floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) or similar. There are lots of non-scikit options